# Removing another role when a specific role added is detected with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm wondering if anyone can help me out with Discord.js snippet of code from my current bot.

I'm looking to add to these lines of codes below to Remove a Role --- So basically my bot is detecting when a role change happens specific to this role being added. Then once it happens, it strips away one of the roles -- if that makes sense?

```
if
  (!oldMem.roles.find(x => x.name === "Inactive") && newMem.roles.find(x => x.name === "Inactive"))
      client.channels.get("547932494259814410").send(`:bell: ${newMem} THere is a new inactive <@&662373687726440461>...`);
```

The role I want to strip from the user is the role ID of 560860499894337538 - Not everyone will have this role although, so I'm hoping this can be done without the BOT erroring out as well.

Comment: Could you show the error?

Answer (score 0):

The code I've added will try to find the role you want to remove and then remove it if it was found.

```
if (!oldMem.roles.find(x => x.name === "Inactive") && newMem.roles.find(x => x.name === "Inactive")) {
    client.channels.get("547932494259814410").send(`:bell: ${newMem} There is a new inactive <@&662373687726440461>...`);

    const role = message.member.roles.get('560860499894337538');

    if (role) newMem.roles.remove(role).catch(console.log);
}
```